# fetch запрос возвращает html страницы

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

При отправке формы со страницы регистрации выполняю fetch запрос для подтверждения успешной авторизации:

```
const autorization = async () => {
    let response = await fetch('/');
    if (response.ok) {
        let autoriz = await response.text();
        console.log(autoriz);
    }
}
```

Но мне возвращается html код страницы. Я предполагаю, что это происходит потому, что сервер еще не успел обработать форму и fetch получает то, что в данный момент отправляет сервер - то-есть текущую страницу. Как это можно исправить?

PS

Я по советам из комментариев сделал также отправку данных через тот-же fetch, но теперь, после обработки сервером, я не получаю ответ в fetch. При этом мне не возвращается никаких ошибок. Оно просто молча не работает.

```
const autorization = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let response = await fetch('/', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: new FormData(formElem)
      });
  
    let autoriz = await response.text();
    alert(autoriz);
}
```

Кроме того, в url страницы отображаются данные из формы...

PS2

Я выяснил, что теперь сервер, почему-то вообще не обрабатывает форму. Что с этим делать?

Comment: Отправка формы на сервер для авторизации,  осуществляется через POST с указанием необходимых заголовков и тела запроса. И ваш сервер должен уметь принимать эти запросы.

Comment: @Rudi, сервер принимает запрос, который отправляется кнопкой submit. Он его обрабатывает и возвращает ответ. Тут все работает, но дальше fetch должен принять ответ, а он срабатывает одновременно с отправкой формы. Поэтому получает код страницы, который в данный момент отдаёт сервер через res.render

Comment: Кнопка submit не имеет никакого отношения к fetch, они создают два совершенно отдельных и никак не связанных HTTP-запроса. Если вы хотите получить ответ на форму через fetch — значит вы должны отправлять форму через этот самый fetch, а не через кнопку submit

Comment: @andreymal, вот это уже ближе, можно пример кода, пожалуйста?

Comment: Есть в документациях про fetch и FormData https://learn.javascript.ru/formdata

Comment: Глеб, вот вы делаете `fetch('/')` - то есть запрашиваете главную страницу сайта. Почему вы ожидаете получить в ответ что-то кроме html-разметки главной страницы сайта?

Comment: Ваша главная проблема в том, что вы не понимаете, как работают http-запросы. Делая fetch('/') вы просо получаете текст с этой страницы, то есть её разметку. Если вы хотите получать какую-то информацию с сервера, вам следует создать отдельную страницу с api. Или же если информацией, которую вы хотите получить является ответ на запрос, то вам вместо `submit` следует использовать `fetch` с методом `POST` и обрабатывать ответ внутри него.

Comment: А что в Вашем случае "подтверждения успешной авторизации"? Какие Ваши ожидания от запроса? Вы как-то обрабатываете этот запрос?

Comment: @Pavel Nazarian, естественно, происходит обработка (данные отправляются в базу данных и возвращается ответ, подтверждающий авторизацию)